# force close in database.getwritable

Tags: android

I have written code below for inserting a set of information in the database but unfortunately it has force close and I don't know why.

I looked at logcat and understood that the problem is with this lin `db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();`

can anyone please help me to understand the reason and solve that?

thanks in advance

mainActivity :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

DBHelper dbHelper = null;
SQLiteDatabase db = null;
ContentValues values = null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    dbHelper = new DBHelper(this, "simple_db", null, 1);

    db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("name", "Barry");
    values.put("amount", "100");
    db.insert("simpletable", "", values);



}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

DBHelper :

```
    public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
Context c;
public DBHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory,
        int version) {

    super(context, name, factory, version);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String creatString = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS simpletable" + 
    "(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + "name TEXT NOT NULL"
    + "amount INTEGER NOT NULL);";

    db.execSQL(creatString);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String dropString = 
            "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS simpletable;";
    db.execSQL(dropString);
    onCreate(db);

}
```

}

Comment: You have to post your stacktrace so we can see what type of Exception you are getting

Comment: Just to warn you. You lack a space and comma between "name TEXT NOT NULL" and "amount..". Please add it so your create table sentence is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your onCreate() method to:

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String creatString = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS simpletable" + 
            "(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + "name TEXT NOT NULL,"
            + "amount INTEGER NOT NULL);";

    db.execSQL(creatString);
}
```

All you'll be all right.

Your CREATE TABLE sentence was mis-constructed, lacking a comma between second and third line.